REDIRECCIÓN WEB EN FUNCIÓN DEL SUBDOMINIO
Dentro de mi red local, tengo dos servidores web, cada uno de ello sirve una aplicación web distinta. Por otro lado, tengo un dominio con dos subdominios y me gustaría acceder a cada servidor con su subdominio, por ejemplo:
app1.midominio.com -> servidor local con IP 192.168.0.10
app2.midominio.com -> servidor local con IP 192.168.0.11
Tengo un router con IP fija.

¿Cómo puede enrrutar las conexiones para que según el subdominio responda uno u otro servidor web?
Actualmente hago una redirección web desde un IIS cambiando el puerto en función del subdominio que hace la consulta. Es decir,

Cuando el IIS recibe la petición de app1.midominio.com, la redirecciona a app1.midominio.com:444, cuando el router recibe la nueava conexión por el puerto 444, la redirige a 192.168.0.10

Cuando el IIS recibe la petición de app2.midominio.com, la redirecciona a app1.midominio.com:445, cuando el router recibe la nueava conexión por el puerto 445, la redirige a 192.168.0.11


Como comentaba, me gustaría cambiar este sistema por un enrrutado sin cambiar el puerto.
Saludos
